# Function for React Native doesn't update the state / doesn't change the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I recently started creating my first React Native app and everything has been going well until I needed to edit the state of the app to present a different page depending on what button the user pressed in the menu. I can call the function (toMerchLink) properly via the menu component. I even added an "alert" to test whether it would work and it did.

Below is my menu component:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Butto } from "react-native";
import BottomNavigation, { Tab } from "react-native-material-bottom-navigation";
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'

class FooterMenu extends React.Component {

  viewedTab = 0

  toMerchLink = () => {

        this.setState({
            page: 'merch'
          });



        alert('Should go to Merch now.')
        this.viewedTab = 1;
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <BottomNavigation
        activeTab={this.viewedTab}
        labelColor="white"
        rippleColor="white"
        style={{
          height: 56,
          elevation: 8,
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          right: 0
        }}
      >

        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#37474F"
          label="Home"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="home"/>}

        />
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#00796B"
          label="Merch"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="shopping-cart"/>}
          onPress={() => this.toMerchLink()}
        />
        <Tab
          barBackgroundColor="#5D4037"
          label="Settings"
          icon={<Icon size={24} color="white" name="book" />}
        />

      </BottomNavigation>
    );
  }
}

export default FooterMenu;
```

And this here is my main App.js which stores the the logic of what to show depending on what the state is. Apologies if this looks sloppy, but I am just trying to get this to work, I will improve it once I understand it more.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import ajax from "./src/ajax";
import CoinList from "./src/components/CoinList";
import FooterMenu from './src/components/Menu';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  /*state = {
    coins: [],
    page: 'merch'
  };*/

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      coins: [],
      page: 'home'
    }
}
  async componentDidMount() {
    const coins = await ajax.fetchInitialCoins();
    this.setState({ coins });
  }
  render() {

    if (this.state.page == "home") {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.coins.length > 0 ? (
          <CoinList coins={this.state.coins} />

        ) : (
          <Text style={styles.header}>Simplebits</Text>
        )}
        <FooterMenu />
      </View>
    );

  }

  if (this.state.page == "merch") {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Merch page</Text>
        <FooterMenu />
      </View>
    );

  }

  if (this.state.page == "settings") {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Settings page</Text>
        <FooterMenu />
      </View>
    );

  }

  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 40
  }
});
```

I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time, but nothing I tried seems to work. It's likely a really simple fix. Would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: a) You need to bind the toMerchLink function to the class, so that `this` equals the class. b) In the constructor, set an initial state to {} (this isn't necessary but I think it's done conventionally

Comment: Also, the way you are showing pages is kind of an anti-pattern in React. Use a Routing library - there's lots to pick from but https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/guides/quick-start is one such example.

Comment: Marvelous. I will look into that now. Thank you, Abid!

Comment: Well I've been trying to implement this, but it's still not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that, the tab press handler (`toMerchLink()`) is updating the state of `FooterMenu` component and you are conditionally rendering component in `App` component. When user press tab you should updated state of `App` component, not the state of `FooterMenu` component.

So the changes will be to pass a `tabPressHandler` to `FooterMenu` component, and call it when user press tab. In the `tabPressHandler` change state of `App` component to update current `page`.

Please consider following snippets

**FooterMenu**

```
class FooterMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={ currentTab: 0}
    }
    ...
    render() {
      return (
        <BottomNavigation
          activeTab={this.state.currentTab}
          labelColor="white"
          rippleColor="white"
          style={{
            height: 56,
            elevation: 8,
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0
          }}
        >
          <Tab
            ...
            onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    currentTab: 0
                });
                this.props.onPressHandler('home');
            }}
          />
          <Tab
            ...
            onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    currentTab: 1
                });
                this.props.onPressHandler('merch');
            }}
          />
          <Tab
            ...
            onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                currentTab: 2
              });
              this.props.onPressHandler('settings');
            }}
          />
      </BottomNavigation>
   );
  }
}
```

**App**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  tabPressHandler = (page) => {
    this.setState({
      page
    });
  }
  ...
  render() {
    ...
    if (this.state.page == "merch") {
      ...
      <FooterMenu onPressHandler={this.tabPressHandler}/>
    }
    if (this.state.page == "settings") {
      ...
      <FooterMenu onPressHandler={this.tabPressHandler}/>
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Try to use any Routing library, navigation would be much easier.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks Prasun! I will definitely check out React Router for my next project as it'll be much easier, but for now I'd like to understand the core concept of how to do it without one just so I don't become dependent on it in case something goes wrong.

Comment: I implemented your code. However, in the Menu.js file when I press any button this "this.props.onPressHandler('home');" part results in an error which tells me that it is not a function. This happens for all 3 buttons. How could I resolve that?

Comment: Have you passed the `onPressHandler` with `FooterMenu`, like `<FooterMenu onPressHandler={this.tabPressHandler}/>`?

Comment: You need to pass the `onPressHandler` function down to the footer in its props

Comment: This is what I currently got as the app.js https://pastebin.com/Ce4mQBtP and this here is my menu.js https://pastebin.com/ijSKEqTz I added some alert functions in the Menu.js for debugging reasons and those seem to work perfectly fine, but I guess the issue still is that it doesn't edit the App.js. I likely messed something up during the integration of your code.

Comment: You are not passing `onPressHandler` for `Home` and `merch`, you have used only `<FooterMenu />`, pass the handler like you did for settings page `<FooterMenu onPressHandler={this.tabPressHandler} />`, please remove the trailing `;` in `settings`.

Comment: BTW, you should also check for `if (this.state.page == "home")` in `App` component, otherwise your code will be errornous.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, Prasun! :) I passed the handler for the other pages as well, I was unable to find the ";" that was exclusive to the settings page that you wanted me to remove. However, I still get an error which reads `_this2.props.onPressHandler is not a function. (In _this2.props.onPressHandler('home'); '_this2.props.onPressHandler' is undefined)`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looking into a routing library as per Prasun Pal's suggestion and I ended up using '[React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)' and it took me just a few minutes to implement it and now everything is working perfectly!